# Unit Test for Login with Jasmine and Karma

Tags: angularjs, authentication, karma-runner

I'm trying to make my project with login function and now I want to make a Unit Test for it. I'm using Karma for my test, but it failed. Could someone please help me to fix my test code right?

Here is my login:

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookieStore) {
   var self = this;
   $scope.invalid = false;
   $scope.username=$cookieStore.username;
   $scope.password=$cookieStore.password;


   this.login=function(){
     $http.post('/login', {
       username=$scope.username,
       password=$scope.password
    }).success(function(data) {
      $cookieStore.put('username');
      $location.url('/');
    })
    .error(function() {
      $scope.password='';
      $scope.invalid=true;
    });
  };
});
```

And here is my Test code:

```
'use strict';
describe('Controller: LoginCtrl', function() {
  var LoginCtrl, $httpBackend, $rootScope, $provide, $location, $cookieStore, scope;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $httpBackend=$injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $rootScope=$injector.get('rootScope');
    $cookieStore=$injector.get('$cookieStore');


    LoginCtrl=function() {
      return $controller('LoginCtrl', { // --> this is error: $controller is not defined
        '$scope': $rootScope,
        '$cookieStore': $cookieStore,
        '$location': $location
      });
    };
  }));

  //This is success
  it('should have a LoginCtrl controller', function() {
    expect('myApp.LoginCtrl').toBeDefined();
  });

  // Failure
  it('should store username and password into cookies', function() {
    var $scope={};
    var loginCtrl=LoginCtrl();
    $scope.username='testUser';
    expect($cookieStore.get('username')).toBe('testUser');
  });

  // Failure
  it('should logs a user in and redirect', function() {
    angular.element('username').enter('testUser'); // --> error: angular.element(...).enter is not a function
    angular.element('password').enter('testPassword');
    angular.element(':button').click();
    expect(location.url).toBe('/'); // --> error: location is not defined
  });
});
```

Comment: What is failing?  What specific error are you getting?

Comment: Hi nweg, as you see my comment in above code that is errors. I just confuse about beforeEach(inject($injector){})); and beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $httpBackend){}));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code for example I have put your login function on scope. I added ngCookie as a dependency on your app and some other stuff you can compare with your original code.

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies'])
 .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location, $cookieStore) {
   $scope.invalid = false;
   console.log($cookieStore);
   $scope.username = $cookieStore.get('username');
   $scope.password = $cookieStore.get('password');

   $scope.login=function() {
     $http.post('/login', {
       username: $scope.username,
       password: $scope.password
    }).success(function(data) {
      $cookieStore.put('username', $scope.username);
      $location.path('/');
    })
    .error(function() {
      $scope.password='';
      $scope.invalid=true;
    });
  };
});
```

And test

```js
describe('Controller: LoginCtrl', function() {
  var LoginCtrl, $httpBackend, $rootScope, $provide, $location, $cookieStore, scope;
  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $httpBackend=$injector.get('$httpBackend');
    $rootScope=$injector.get('$rootScope');
    $cookieStore=$injector.get('$cookieStore');
    $controller=$injector.get('$controller');
    $location=$injector.get('$location');


    LoginCtrl=function() {
      return $controller('LoginCtrl', { 
        '$scope': $rootScope,
        '$cookie': $cookieStore,
        '$location': $location
      });
    };
  }));

  //This is success
  it('should have a LoginCtrl controller', function() {
    expect('myApp.LoginCtrl').toBeDefined();
  });

  // You have to think about what you want to test here. There is no logic in your controller
  // that matches what you test here. To activate test just remove the x from xit.
  xit('should store username and password into cookies', function() {
    var $scope={};
    var loginCtrl=LoginCtrl();
    $rootScope.username='testUser';
    expect($cookieStore.get('username')).toBe('testUser');
  });

  // Failure
  it('should logs a user in and redirect', function() {
    var loginCtrl=LoginCtrl();
    
    $httpBackend.whenPOST('/login').respond(200);
    $rootScope.username = 'testUser';
    $rootScope.password = 'password';
    $rootScope.login();
    
    $httpBackend.flush();
    $rootScope.$digest();
    expect($location.path()).toBe('/'); // --> error: location is not defined
    expect($cookieStore.get('username')).toBe('testUser');
  });
});
```

I didn't really understand what you wanted to test in your second test as I mention in a comment in the snippet.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/eiKVs3aXR1KR09VHkssK?p=preview
```

I hope this helps you on your way.

Comment: I see new things when I look at your code again. When you get $rootScope from injector you have forgotten the $ in the beginning. I the second test you get the error location is not defined. This variable should be $location. So take a look at your variables and see that they match.

Comment: Hi hesa,
It still not working, I'm just learning angular for a few days, and I can't find anythings else to fix it. Could you write example for my login? and could tell me what is deference between:
beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $httpBackend) {}));
and
beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
$rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
$httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
}));
Thanks so much.

Comment: By the way, I also think that we should put a user and login function into test cases, but I don't know what exactly it is.
Can I do this:
beforeEach(module('myApp'), function($provide) {
mockBackend = jasmine.createSkyObj('login',[])
});

beforeEach(inject(function($injector, loginFunc) {
loginFunc=$httpBackend.when('GET','/login').respond({'username':'tester','password':'testpass'});
}));

it('put user', function() {
loginFunc.login.then(function($cookieStore) {
expect($cookieStore).toBe('tester');
expect($cookieStore).toBe('testpass');
});

Comment: You can do what you are asking for but with a different syntax. If you put this in the code I provided above I think it will work